# USB Debugging setting is disabled (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge)

Tags: android, settings, usb-debugging

Can someone tell me, why the setting to enable "USB Debugging" is disabled and how I can enable it? Here is a screenshot of my settings page.
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycFXq.png)

My Phone is a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with the Android version 5.1.1

Comment: Did you try looking for the answer at all? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=galaxy%20s6%20enable%20usb%20debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution on my own... Here's the Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj5uiUNprRk

Answer (score 4):

On 2024 theres a new feature that blocks that, It happened to me after enabling "Apps Autoblocker". Disable that and it can enable you to use USB Debugging

https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/mobile-devices/protect-your-galaxy-device-with-the-new-auto-blocker-feature/